# How to get all the checked boxes of several trees in a same window?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, selecteditem

**What I am dealing with :**

I am working on a window with several Checkboxes Trees (Java Swing) and I used samples of codes that I found in stackoverflow to make a JTree with JCheckBox objects. So I made a class CheckBoxNode, a class CheckBoxNodeRenderer and a class CheckBoxNodeEditor.
Nevertheless, I don't understand what really happens when I check a box in a tree. I used a very simple "println" to see what happens in many functions like getTreeCellRendererComponent of the class CheckBoxNodeRenderer for instance.

**What I would like to do :**

I have three trees and I would like to get all the checked elements of each tree in a separate element, an array or an ArrayList. So then, I can work with the selected elements with just reading these arrays or ArrayLists. Of course, if I uncheck a box, the element must be removed from the array.

**What I already tried :**

I have to admit that I didn't have many ideas. I tried to understand exactly what happens when I check a box, with logs in many functions and I could observe that when I check an element in a tree, my logs are written more than three times (for instance a log in getTreeCellRenderer).

**My code :**

```
class CheckBoxNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1155080395876568819L;
    private String _title;
    private boolean _selectedStatus;

    public CheckBoxNode(String name, boolean isSelected) {
        this._title = name;
        this._selectedStatus = isSelected;
    }

    //GETTERS

    public String getTitle() {
        return this._title;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return this._selectedStatus;
    }

    //SETTERS

    public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
        this._title = newTitle;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this._selectedStatus = isSelected;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return _title;
    }
}
```

CheckBoxNodeEditor

```
class CheckBoxNodeEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2616799535763664121L;
    private CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();

    //CONSTRUCTOR 

    public CheckBoxNodeEditor() {}

    //METHODS

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        JCheckBox checkBox = renderer.getNodeRenderer();
        CheckBoxNode checkBoxNode = new CheckBoxNode(checkBox.getText(), checkBox.isSelected());
        return checkBoxNode;
    }

    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
        Component editor = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                true, expanded, leaf, row, true);
        // editor always selected / focused
        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
                if (stopCellEditing()) {
                    fireEditingStopped();
                }
            }
        };

        if (editor instanceof JCheckBox) {
            ((JCheckBox) editor).addItemListener(itemListener);
        }
        return editor;
    }
}
```

CheckBoxNodeRenderer

```
class CheckBoxNodeRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

    private JCheckBox nodeRenderer = new JCheckBox();
    private Color selectionForeground, selectionBackground, textForeground, textBackground;

    //CONSTRUCTOR

    public CheckBoxNodeRenderer() {
        Font fontValue;
        fontValue = UIManager.getFont("Tree.font");
        if (fontValue != null) {
            nodeRenderer.setFont(fontValue);
        }
        Boolean booleanValue = (Boolean) UIManager.get("Tree.drawsFocusBorderAroundIcon");
        nodeRenderer.setFocusPainted((booleanValue != null)&& (booleanValue.booleanValue()));
        selectionForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground");
        selectionBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground");
        textForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground");
        textBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground");
    }

    //METHODS

    protected JCheckBox getNodeRenderer() {
        return nodeRenderer;
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {
        Component returnValue;
        String stringValue = tree.convertValueToText(value, selected, expanded,
                leaf, row, false);
        nodeRenderer.setText(stringValue);
        nodeRenderer.setSelected(false);
        nodeRenderer.setEnabled(tree.isEnabled());
        if (selected) {
            nodeRenderer.setForeground(selectionForeground);
            nodeRenderer.setBackground(selectionBackground);
        } else {
            nodeRenderer.setForeground(textForeground);
            nodeRenderer.setBackground(textBackground);
        }
        if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
            Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value)
                    .getUserObject();
            if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
                CheckBoxNode node = (CheckBoxNode) userObject;
                nodeRenderer.setText(node.getTitle());
                nodeRenderer.setSelected(node.isSelected());
            }
        }
        returnValue = nodeRenderer;
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Building the window and the trees : consists in extracting data from a database and building the checkboxes trees as well as the main window of the application containing the trees and other panels

```
public class WindowBuilding extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -634017858375515775L;
    private Parser _parser;

    // CONSTRUCTOR

    public WindowBuilding() {
        this._parser = new Parser();                        //parser to extract data from the database containining all the informations
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));  //gridlayout to have all the elements in the same window

    }

    // METHODS

    public void buildTrees() throws SQLException {
        _parser.extractData();
        _parser.sortModels();
        _parser.sortCustomers();
        _parser.sortGroups();

        System.out.println(_parser.getNumberOfCustomers());
        System.out.println(_parser.getNumberOfGroups());

        // Families, Types and Models arrays
        CheckBoxNode[] myFamilies = new CheckBoxNode[_parser.getNumberOfFamilies()];
        CheckBoxNode[] myTypes = new CheckBoxNode[_parser.getNumberOfTypes()];
        CheckBoxNode[] myModels = new CheckBoxNode[_parser.getNumberOfModels()];

        // Root
        CheckBoxNode root = new CheckBoxNode("All", false);

        // Complete the arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < _parser.getNumberOfFamilies(); i++) {
            myFamilies[i] = new CheckBoxNode(_parser.getFamily(i), false);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _parser.getNumberOfTypes(); i++) {
            myTypes[i] = new CheckBoxNode(_parser.getType(i), false);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _parser.getNumberOfModels(); i++) {
            myModels[i] = new CheckBoxNode(_parser.getModel(i), false);
        }

        // Add Models to Types
        for (int i = 0; i < myModels.length; i++) {
            if (myModels[i].toString().startsWith("T119")) {
                myTypes[1].add(myModels[i]);
            }
            if (myModels[i].toString().startsWith("T120")) {
                myTypes[2].add(myModels[i]);
            }
            if (myModels[i].toString().startsWith("T121")) {
                myTypes[3].add(myModels[i]);
            }
            if (myModels[i].toString().startsWith("T130")) {
                myTypes[4].add(myModels[i]);
            }
            if (myModels[i].toString().startsWith("T150")) {
                myTypes[7].add(myModels[i]);
            }
        }

        // Add Types to Families
        for (int i = 0; i < myTypes.length; i++) {
            if (myTypes[i].toString().startsWith("T119") || myTypes[i].toString().startsWith("T12")) {
                myFamilies[0].add(myTypes[i]);
            }
            if (myTypes[i].toString().startsWith("T13")) {
                myFamilies[1].add(myTypes[i]);
            }
            if (myTypes[i].toString().startsWith("T15")) {
                myFamilies[3].add(myTypes[i]);
            }
        }

        // Add Families to Root
        for (int i = 0; i < _parser.getNumberOfFamilies(); i++) {
            if (i != 2) {
                root.add(myFamilies[i]);
            }
        }

        // Customers and Groups arrays
        CheckBoxNode[] myCustomers = new CheckBoxNode[_parser.getNumberOfCompanies()];
        CheckBoxNode[] myGroups = new CheckBoxNode[_parser.getNumberOfFleets()];

        // Root for Groups
        CheckBoxNode rootGroups = new CheckBoxNode("All", false);

        // Complete the arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < _parser.getNumberOfCustomers(); i++) {
            myCustomers[i] = new CheckBoxNode(_parser.getCustomer(i), false);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _parser.getNumberOfGroups(); i++) {
            myGroups[i] = new CheckBoxNode(_parser.getGroup(i), false);
        }

        // Add Groups to Customers
        for (int i = 0; i < myCustomers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Groups.length; j++) {
                if (myFleets[j].getTitle()
                        .startsWith(myCustomers[i].getTitle())) {
                    myCustomers[i].add(myGroups[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Add Companies to Root
        for (int i = 0; i < myCustomers.length; i++) {
            rootGroups.add(myCustomers[i]);
        }

        // Test Types array
        CheckBoxNode[] myTests = new CheckBoxNode[8];

        // Root
        CheckBoxNode rootTests = new CheckBoxNode("All", false);

        // Complete the arrays
        myTests[0] = new CheckBoxNode("FIRST TEST", false);
        myTests[1] = new CheckBoxNode("SECOND TEST", false);
        myTests[2] = new CheckBoxNode("CHECK TEST", false);
        myTests[3] = new CheckBoxNode("RUN TEST", false);
        myTests[4] = new CheckBoxNode("STATIC", false);
        myTests[5] = new CheckBoxNode("TYPICAL TEST", false);
        myTests[6] = new CheckBoxNode("SIMU VALIDATION", false);
        myTests[7] = new CheckBoxNode("OTHER", false);

        // Add Test Types to root
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            rootTests.add(myTests[i]);
        }

        // TPP Array
        CheckBoxNode[] myTpp = new CheckBoxNode[30];

        // Root 
        CheckBoxNode rootTpp = new CheckBoxNode("All", false);

        // Complete the arrays
        for(int i=0; i<30; i++) {
            myTpp[i] = new CheckBoxNode("TPP "+(i+1), false);
        }

        // Add Tpp to root
        for(int i=0; i<myTpp.length; i++) {
            rootTpp.add(myTpp[i]);
        }


        // Create objects JTree
        JTree treeProducts = new JTree(root);
        JTree treeGroups = new JTree(rootGroups);
        JTree treeTests = new JTree(rootTests);
        JTree treeTpp = new JTree(rootTpp);

        // Trees renderer
        CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();

        // Products tree parameters
        treeProducts.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        treeProducts.setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor());
        treeProducts.setEditable(true);

        // Groups tree parameters
        treeGroups.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        treeGroups.setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor());
        treeGroups.setEditable(true);

        // Test Types tree parameters
        treeTests.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        treeTests.setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor());
        treeTests.setEditable(true);

        // Tpp tree parameters
        treeTpp.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        treeTpp.setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor());
        treeTpp.setEditable(true);

        // Building panels
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel dataPropPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel spinnersPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel msnPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel datePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel selectTppPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel tppPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel descPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel labelsPanel= new JPanel();
        JPanel fieldsPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        spinnersPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(spinnersPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        labelsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        fieldsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(fieldsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        descPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(descPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        tppPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tppPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        msnPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(msnPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        datePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(datePanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        titlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        dataPropPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        selectTppPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        // Dimensions
        Dimension dimLabel = new Dimension(300,35);

        // JScrollPane for trees
        JScrollPane prodPane = new JScrollPane(treeProducts);           // ScrollPane products
        prodPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(250,300));
        JScrollPane groupPane = new JScrollPane(treeGroups);            // ScrollPane groups
        groupPpane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(250,300));
        JScrollPane tePane = new JScrollPane(treeTests);
        tePane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(250,300));
        JScrollPane tppPane = new JScrollPane(treeTpp);
        tppPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,300));

        // Labels for main panel
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Generate Test Points");
        titlePanel.add(title);
        JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("Data properties");
        dataPropPanel.add(topLabel);
        JLabel bottomLabel = new JLabel("Select TPP");
        selectTppPanel.add(bottomLabel);

        // MSN Panel
        SpinnerModel model1 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,10000,1);
        SpinnerModel model2 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,10000,1);
        JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(model1);
        JSpinner spinner2 = new JSpinner(model2);
        msnPanel.add(spinner1);
        msnPanel.add(new JLabel("   to   "));
        msnPanel.add(spinner2);
        msnPanel.setMaximumSize(dimLabel);

        // Date Panel
        SpinnerModel date1 = new SpinnerDateModel();
        SpinnerModel date2 = new SpinnerDateModel();
        JSpinner dateSpinner1 = new JSpinner(date1);
        JSpinner dateSpinner2 = new JSpinner(date2);
        datePanel.add(dateSpinner1);
        datePanel.add(new JLabel("   to   "));
        datePanel.add(dateSpinner2);
        datePanel.setMaximumSize(dimLabel);

        // Spinners Panel
        JLabel msnRangeLabel = new JLabel("MSN Range");
        spinnersPanel.add(msnRangeLabel);
        spinnersPanel.add(msnPanel);
        spinnersPanel.add(new JLabel("Test Date Range"));
        spinnersPanel.add(datePanel);

        // Top Panel
        JLabel acPropertiesLabel = new JLabel("Product properties");
        topPanel.add(prodPropertiesLabel);
        topPanel.add(prodPane);
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Groups"));
        topPanel.add(groupPane);
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Test properties"));
        topPanel.add(tePane);
        topPanel.add(spinnersPanel);

        // Labels Panel
        JLabel tppName = new JLabel("TPP Name");
        tppName.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,35));
        labelsPanel.add(tppName);
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("TPP List"));

        // Fields Panel
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,35));
        fieldsPanel.add(textField);
        fieldsPanel.add(tppane);

        // TPP Panel
        tppPanel.add(labelsPanel);
        tppPanel.add(fieldsPanel);

        // Desc Panel
        descPanel.add(new JLabel("label for description"));
        descPanel.add(new JLabel("label for description"));
        descPanel.add(new JLabel("label for description"));
        descPanel.add(new JLabel("label for description"));
        descPanel.add(new JLabel("label for description"));

        // Bottom Panel
        bottomPanel.add(tppPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(descPanel);

        // Main Panel
        mainPanel.add(titlePanel);
        mainPanel.add(dataPropPanel);
        mainPanel.add(topPanel);
        mainPanel.add(selectTppPanel);
        mainPanel.add(bottomPanel);
        this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);

        // Window parameters
        ((JComponent) this.getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));   //add a border to the window
        this.setSize(1600,900);
        this.setTitle("Generate Test Points");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class TestPointGeneration {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ParserConfigurationException 
     * @throws SAXException 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        WindowBuilding window = new WindowBuilding();
        window.buildTrees();
        window.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more information about my code and I'm very grateful to all of you.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Setting breakpoints could provide a lot more information than logging.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. Yes you're right but I couldn't obtain any more information with breakpoints here.

Comment: Could you post your main class please?

Comment: @sirandy Sure, I added the WindowBuilding class which is the biggest one extracting data and building the checkboxes trees and the main class which is pretty simple. I don't think you need the Parser class, it's just to connect the app to the SQL Server and extract the data that I need. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I have your program running. As I understand you want to get the checked elements, is it right?

Comment: @sirandy Yes it's right. For the moment I do not have any JButton in my program but I'm adding two buttons (something like a "Next" and a "Clear" or "Cancel"), and when I click on the "Next" I will need to get all the checked elements to use them for many operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted the solution from this answer:
[How to get all the checked boxes of several trees in a same window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186920/how-to-get-all-the-checked-boxes-of-several-trees-in-a-same-window?noredirect=1#comment77428703_45186920)

I think your class CheckBoxNode is missing functionality, basically is a repo information for the status, but then in your CheckBoxNodeEditor class you are adding just a JCheckBox, in my opinion it must be an array or list, and checkBoxNode must handle the events to review if they are checked or unchecked.

Main Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4648172894076113183L;

    public Main() {
        super();
        setSize(500, 500);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final JCheckBoxTree cbt = new JCheckBoxTree();
        final JButton button = new JButton("get checked");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(cbt);
        panel.add(button);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                printChecked(cbt);
            }
        });

        cbt.addCheckChangeEventListener(new JCheckBoxTree.CheckChangeEventListener() {
            public void checkStateChanged(JCheckBoxTree.CheckChangeEvent event) {
                printChecked(cbt);
            }
        });         
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void printChecked(final JCheckBoxTree cbt) {
        System.out.println("Select items");
        TreePath[] paths = cbt.getCheckedPaths();
        for (TreePath tp : paths) {
            for (Object pathPart : tp.getPath()) {
                System.out.print(pathPart + ",");
            }                   
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

JTree Class

```
package com.stackoverflow.checkedboxes;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.EventListener;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class JCheckBoxTree extends JTree {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4194122328392241790L;

    JCheckBoxTree selfPointer = this;



    // Defining data structure that will enable to fast check-indicate the state of each node
    // It totally replaces the "selection" mechanism of the JTree
    private class CheckedNode {
        boolean isSelected;
        boolean hasChildren;
        boolean allChildrenSelected;

        public CheckedNode(boolean isSelected_, boolean hasChildren_, boolean allChildrenSelected_) {
            isSelected = isSelected_;
            hasChildren = hasChildren_;
            allChildrenSelected = allChildrenSelected_;
        }
    }
    HashMap<TreePath, CheckedNode> nodesCheckingState;
    HashSet<TreePath> checkedPaths = new HashSet<TreePath>();

    // Defining a new event type for the checking mechanism and preparing event-handling mechanism
    protected EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

    public class CheckChangeEvent extends EventObject {     
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8100230309044193368L;

        public CheckChangeEvent(Object source) {
            super(source);          
        }       
    }   

    public interface CheckChangeEventListener extends EventListener {
        public void checkStateChanged(CheckChangeEvent event);
    }

    public void addCheckChangeEventListener(CheckChangeEventListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(CheckChangeEventListener.class, listener);
    }
    public void removeCheckChangeEventListener(CheckChangeEventListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(CheckChangeEventListener.class, listener);
    }

    void fireCheckChangeEvent(CheckChangeEvent evt) {
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
            if (listeners[i] == CheckChangeEventListener.class) {
                ((CheckChangeEventListener) listeners[i + 1]).checkStateChanged(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    // Override
    public void setModel(TreeModel newModel) {
        super.setModel(newModel);
        resetCheckingState();
    }

    // New method that returns only the checked paths (totally ignores original "selection" mechanism)
    public TreePath[] getCheckedPaths() {
        return checkedPaths.toArray(new TreePath[checkedPaths.size()]);
    }

    // Returns true in case that the node is selected, has children but not all of them are selected
    public boolean isSelectedPartially(TreePath path) {
        CheckedNode cn = nodesCheckingState.get(path);
        return cn.isSelected && cn.hasChildren && !cn.allChildrenSelected;
    }

    private void resetCheckingState() { 
        nodesCheckingState = new HashMap<TreePath, CheckedNode>();
        checkedPaths = new HashSet<TreePath>();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)getModel().getRoot();
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        addSubtreeToCheckingStateTracking(node);
    }

    // Creating data structure of the current model for the checking mechanism
    private void addSubtreeToCheckingStateTracking(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        TreeNode[] path = node.getPath();   
        TreePath tp = new TreePath(path);
        CheckedNode cn = new CheckedNode(false, node.getChildCount() > 0, false);
        nodesCheckingState.put(tp, cn);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < node.getChildCount() ; i++) {              
            addSubtreeToCheckingStateTracking((DefaultMutableTreeNode) tp.pathByAddingChild(node.getChildAt(i)).getLastPathComponent());
        }
    }

    // Overriding cell renderer by a class that ignores the original "selection" mechanism
    // It decides how to show the nodes due to the checking-mechanism
    private class CheckBoxCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TreeCellRenderer {     
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7341833835878991719L;     
        JCheckBox checkBox;     
        public CheckBoxCellRenderer() {
            super();
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            checkBox = new JCheckBox();
            add(checkBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
                boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
                boolean hasFocus) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;
            Object obj = node.getUserObject();          
            TreePath tp = new TreePath(node.getPath());
            CheckedNode cn = nodesCheckingState.get(tp);
            if (cn == null) {
                return this;
            }
            checkBox.setSelected(cn.isSelected);
            checkBox.setText(obj.toString());
            checkBox.setOpaque(cn.isSelected && cn.hasChildren && ! cn.allChildrenSelected);
            return this;
        }       
    }

    public JCheckBoxTree() {
        super();
        // Disabling toggling by double-click
        this.setToggleClickCount(0);
        // Overriding cell renderer by new one defined above
        CheckBoxCellRenderer cellRenderer = new CheckBoxCellRenderer();
        this.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);

        // Overriding selection model by an empty one
        DefaultTreeSelectionModel dtsm = new DefaultTreeSelectionModel() {      
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -8190634240451667286L;
            // Totally disabling the selection mechanism
            public void setSelectionPath(TreePath path) {
            }           
            public void addSelectionPath(TreePath path) {                       
            }           
            public void removeSelectionPath(TreePath path) {
            }
            public void setSelectionPaths(TreePath[] pPaths) {
            }
        };
        // Calling checking mechanism on mouse click
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                TreePath tp = selfPointer.getPathForLocation(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());
                if (tp == null) {
                    return;
                }
                boolean checkMode = ! nodesCheckingState.get(tp).isSelected;
                checkSubTree(tp, checkMode);
                updatePredecessorsWithCheckMode(tp, checkMode);
                // Firing the check change event
                fireCheckChangeEvent(new CheckChangeEvent(new Object()));
                // Repainting tree after the data structures were updated
                selfPointer.repaint();                          
            }           
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {         
            }           
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {              
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {             
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }           
        });
        this.setSelectionModel(dtsm);
    }

    // When a node is checked/unchecked, updating the states of the predecessors
    protected void updatePredecessorsWithCheckMode(TreePath tp, boolean check) {
        TreePath parentPath = tp.getParentPath();
        // If it is the root, stop the recursive calls and return
        if (parentPath == null) {
            return;
        }       
        CheckedNode parentCheckedNode = nodesCheckingState.get(parentPath);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) parentPath.getLastPathComponent();     
        parentCheckedNode.allChildrenSelected = true;
        parentCheckedNode.isSelected = false;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < parentNode.getChildCount() ; i++) {                
            TreePath childPath = parentPath.pathByAddingChild(parentNode.getChildAt(i));
            CheckedNode childCheckedNode = nodesCheckingState.get(childPath);           
            // It is enough that even one subtree is not fully selected
            // to determine that the parent is not fully selected
            if (! childCheckedNode.allChildrenSelected) {
                parentCheckedNode.allChildrenSelected = false;      
            }
            // If at least one child is selected, selecting also the parent
            if (childCheckedNode.isSelected) {
                parentCheckedNode.isSelected = true;
            }
        }
        if (parentCheckedNode.isSelected) {
            checkedPaths.add(parentPath);
        } else {
            checkedPaths.remove(parentPath);
        }
        // Go to upper predecessor
        updatePredecessorsWithCheckMode(parentPath, check);
    }

    // Recursively checks/unchecks a subtree
    protected void checkSubTree(TreePath tp, boolean check) {
        CheckedNode cn = nodesCheckingState.get(tp);
        cn.isSelected = check;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tp.getLastPathComponent();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < node.getChildCount() ; i++) {              
            checkSubTree(tp.pathByAddingChild(node.getChildAt(i)), check);
        }
        cn.allChildrenSelected = check;
        if (check) {
            checkedPaths.add(tp);
        } else {
            checkedPaths.remove(tp);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]
Output:
    Select items
    JTree,colors,blue,
    JTree,colors,red,
    JTree,colors,
    JTree,colors,yellow,
    JTree,

Comment: Thank you sirandy. I also share a solution I wrote. The advantage is that I get only the names of checked boxes. Nevertheless with your solution it will be easier to check all the children of a checkbox when I check it like colors.
`public Object getCellEditorValue() {
  JCheckBox checkBox = renderer.getNodeRenderer();
  CheckBoxNode checkBoxNode = new CheckBoxNode(checkBox.getText(), checkBox.isSelected());
  if(checkBox.isSelected()) {
   window.addSelectedElement(checkBox.getText());
  } else {
   window.removeUnselectedElement(checkBox.getText());
  }
  return checkBoxNode;
 }`